# Cannot set the value of lightning:inputfield when its a picklist and using lightning:recordEditForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Related to a previous question but with a reproducible example, i just can't seem to set the value of any picklist fields when using lightning:inputField, any ideas?

Component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome, force:hasRecordId">
    <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:500px">
        <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm" 
                                     recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                     objectApiName="Contact">
            <lightning:messages />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="FirstName" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" aura:id="lastname"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Birthdate" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Phone" />
            <!--Picklist-->
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Country__c" aura:id="Country__c"/>
            <lightning:button label="Update" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.update}"/>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </div>    
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({    
    update: function(component, event, helper) {
        //alert(component.find("Country__c"));
        component.find("Country__c").set("v.value", "Ireland");
    },

})
```

Comment: <lightning:inputField fieldName="LeadSource" aura:id="LeadSource" value=""/>

Comment: ^Adding **value** attribute to the picklist will work with the same code.

Comment: @YsrShk that worked! if you add it as an answer i'll accept it

Comment: Paul, can you edit your original question with this example data please? Never mind - I did it. Add the answer and I will delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<lightning:inputField fieldName="LeadSource" aura:id="LeadSource" value=""/>`

Please add an **Value** attribute to the inputfield component.